# Setting HelpText for button from code behind is not working in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, accessibility

I am trying Accessibility for reading help text in voice over. Setting HelpText for button from code behind is not working in Xamarin.Forms.

Code snippet is below. Can anyone help me?

```
AutomationProperties.SetHelpText(Button, "Help text property for the button");
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Is your Button defined in Xaml or code-behind? Please provide more information.

Comment: I am not getting any error. My button is defined in code-behind

Comment: Post all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the button in Code-Behind, this is how to do it

Declare a button

```
var myButton = new Button();
```

Set its acessibility, `InAccessibleTree` is a boolean that is determines if this element is accessible. You must set this to true, in order for the other elements to be used.

```
myButton.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);
```

Then, set your property

```
myButton.SetValue(AutomationProperties.HelpText, "Help text property for the button");
```

So, in the end:

```
var myButton = new Button();
myButton.SetValue(AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTreeProperty, true);
myButton.SetValue(AutomationProperties.HelpText, "Help text property for the button");
```